# Yii::app()->user->id; is returning username instead of id number

Tags: php, yii

I have a very strange problem in that on one machine `Yii::app()->user->id;` returns the username, but on another machine running identical code I'm getting the id number as expected. 
How could `Yii::app()->user->id` be getting the username? What have I missed?

Comment: Do you have a custom UserIdentity class in your app? If yes, where did you put it and what's its class name?

Comment: I am using Yii::app()->user->userid for user id.

Answer (score 5):

first at all,Let's take a look at what happened after user login.

after

```
    $identity->authenticate();
```

if

```
    $identity->errorCode===UserIdentity::ERROR_NONE
```

then we will go the login action

```
    Yii::app()->user->login($identity,$duration)
```

and what behind the login?

I have scan the source of yii
the main idea is the

```
    $this->changeIdentity($id,$identity->getName(),$states);
```

in login function of CWebUser class.

below is changeIdentity function

```
    protected function changeIdentity($id,$name,$states)
{ 
    Yii::app()->getSession()->regenerateID(true);
    $this->setId($id);
    $this->setName($name);
    $this->loadIdentityStates($states);
}
```

secondly:
Let's look back the problem

```
    Yii::app()->user->id;
```

It means to run the getId() method of you class which extends CWebUser, and you config it in sites(the root of you application)/protected/config/main.php like this:

```
    'components'=>array(
    'user'=>array(
        'class'=>'WebUser',
        // enable cookie-based authentication
        'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
    ),
```

In my case ,the class extends CWebUser is WebUser.

In WebUser ,there is  not getId() method, the method will be inherited from CWebUser, because WebUser extends from CWebUser. so this is getId() method from CWebUser.

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.13/framework/web/auth/CWebUser.php#LC287

```
     public function getId()
{
    return $this->getState('__id');
}
```

so when does the  '__id'  set at?
obviously, it is set at the statement of changeIdentity function:

```
    $this->setId($id);
```

and where do the arguement $id value come from?
we know it at below code in class CWebUser:

```
    public function login($identity,$duration=0)
{ 
    $id=$identity->getId();


    $states=$identity->getPersistentStates();



    if($this->beforeLogin($id,$states,false))
    {
        $this->changeIdentity($id,$identity->getName(),$states);

        if($duration>0)
        {
            if($this->allowAutoLogin)
                $this->saveToCookie($duration);
            else
                throw new CException(Yii::t('yii','{class}.allowAutoLogin must be set true in order to use cookie-based authentication.',
                    array('{class}'=>get_class($this))));
        }

        $this->afterLogin(false);
    }
    return !$this->getIsGuest();
}
```

the

```
    $id = $identity->getId();
```

so we can only add a getId function in $idenity, it means we add getId funciton in 
UserIdentity which extend CUserIdentity,like this:

```
public function getId()
{
    return $this->_id;
}
```

and

```
public function setId($id)
{
    $this->_id = $id;
    return;
}
```

when user login successfully, we can pass the user_id to setId($id) in authenticate function of UserIdentity which extends CUserIdentity ,like this:
    public function authenticate()
    {

```
    $record=User::model()->findByAttributes(array('user_name'=>$this->username));

    if($record===null)
        $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
    else if($record->password!==md5($this->password))
        $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
    else
    {
        $this->setId($record->user_id);


        $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_NONE;
    }
    return !$this->errorCode;
}
```

Comment: This doesnt address the question directly, please try and provide a relevant answer

Comment: @PeteMitchell   I am sorry ,I guess I have misunderstand the question..I will take a look to the code source of yii,and  edit the answer again,Thank you!

Comment: @PeteMitchell  I find out, and solve the problem. please take a look, and I am happy to get callback!

Answer (score 3):

You have to override method `getId()` in your `UserIdentity` class.

In your identity class, simply add this:

```
private $_id;

public function getId()
{
    return $this->_id;
}
```

and then finally you could set id by using

```
$this->_id = $user->id
```

More on it, please refer this link:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth#defining-identity-class

Answer (score 1):

Try this, set username:

```
$this->_id=$user->id;
$this->username=$user->username;
```

Answer (score 0):

you have two way to solve this:

```
1) Yii::app()->user->setState("id",$user->id);
2) Yii::app()->user->id = $user->id;
```

both way uses $_SESSION in order to save the value.

then you can retriwe the value like that:

```
Yii::app()->user->id;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this `Yii::app()->user->getId()`

Answer (score 0):

Even I got the same problem, everything is ok but rather id I got username. 
You check your Useridentity file.
In the else part you may miss something like pointer(->).

```
    {
        $this->_id = $user->id; /*here u might miss pointer -> */
        // print_r($this->_id);exit;
        $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_NONE;
    }
```

Hope it'll help you hurshid.

Answer (score -1):

yii default installation sets user id as the name of the user (admin or demo by default) .
If you change the user script and use sql and do the recommended modifications for that, id is returned as the id field in the table .